# The Video is playing using iframe in a website.

Tags: video, iframe

Actually, The video is playing using iframe in a website as of now. But I want to change the iframe to alternate way. Because I should not use iframe concept in a website. Is there any other way to play a video?

Comment: you can use simple <video> tag

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with <video>. But it's not running. Before that i have tried embed it's running well in chrome not in firefox.

Comment: try my example in all browser if it is working or not, you may be doing something wrong

Comment: It means you are doing something wrong ,answer is correct :)

Comment: Mandeep, I'm not saying your answer is wrong. Somewhat problem is there in my site i think so. Because its shows like "No video with supported format and MIME type found." Do you know why?

Comment: which format you r using? formats which are supportable are MP4,WebM,Ogg

Comment: if answer is correct, then you can upvote or mark him correct so tht people looking for answers can have the right answer :)

Comment: Blogilicious_Edit.mp4?rel=0&amp;amp;controls=0&amp;amp;showinfo=0. May I know why they have mention those things after the extension? If i remove those things which after the extension then video is running. and I voteup for you.

Comment: may be they were sending details for controls while sending the details for video, you can simply put src="Blogilicious_Edit.mp4" and give your attributes as needed, i think u can end my efforts now :D :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<video>` tag

Check this demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdLrvcu7/)

**HTML**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://tutorialehtml.com/assets_tutorials/media/Shaun-the-Sheep-The-Movie-Official-Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For more you can read here on video tag

[Video Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_video.asp)

**P.S.** : Video used is from https://tutorialehtml.com/

It is supported in all **browsers** :

**Chrome**  4.0+

**IE**      9.0+

**Mozilla** 3.5+

**Safari**  4.0+

**Opera**   10.5+